# Would you suggest the "mailto" way if there's no knowledge of "PHP coding?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, contacts, mailto

I'm in hurry to upload the template that I already edited and have no time to learn PHP.

Do you suggest the link below as a "temporary way" of displaying my contact info till the day I learn PHP coding? A code like [this](http://geekthis.net/blog/149/website-contact-form-without-php) link?

Comment: Well if you don't know PHP you obviously can't code a contact form in PHP, so... What's wrong with just putting your email address and business phone number, and letting the user write their own email?

Comment: I know... so "mailto" is the only option for now?

Comment: I'm totally agree with you. Actually I am afraid of spams and Some people consider "mailto" way as "unprofessional" and "unsafe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a 3rd party mail service (maybe such as an API where you can send requests in order to send mail) or using PHP (or other server side languages) to send mail from the server directly, I don't believe there is any other option.

`mailto` seems to be your best bet.

Comment: Oh many thanks. Can you please tell me your opinion about the link I mentioned above?

Comment: There isn't really much of an opinion to give,  feel free to use it if you want.  :D

Comment: Oh, and btw, you could always have some sort of spam filter.  For instance, write the mailto email backwards, then have that script reverse it.

Comment: Very helpful! many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.jotform.com/ to create form in order to send e-mail without PHP skill.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Many of those "form offering" generators aren't really free. How about jotform.com?

Comment: You can see in pricing page: http://www.jotform.com/pricing